# (Firebase) Firestore security rules - allow if email verified without custom tokens?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is there a way to check if the request user email is verified in the Firestore security rules?

something like:

```
function isEmailVerified() {
  return request.auth.emailVerified == true;
}
```

Comment: That should be `request.auth.token.email_verified` as far as I can tell.

Comment: is there a reference of the token data? or a way to inspect the token?

Comment: To inspect you can decode the JWT in your app or through jwt.io. The documentation is definitely sparse, but I dug it up from https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken

Comment: sharp eye, i looked for something like this for over an hour. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
request.auth.token.email_verified
```

If you want to know all claims available in your token, you can decode the JWT in your app or through jwt.io.

Some relevant documentation:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#auth
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken (for a list of the claims in there by default)