# Create a firebase cloud function that detects emailVerified change

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a cloud function with firebase functions to detect if the user emailVerified prop changes.
This is what I currently have in my index.js in functions folder:

```
exports.emailVerifiedChange = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user)=> {
    if(user.emailVerified) {
        admin.firestore().collection(`users`).doc(user.uid).create({
            created: new Date(),
            uid: user.uid,
            name: user.displayName,
            searchName: user.displayName.toLowerCase(),
            userInfo: {
              profilePic: '',
              phoneNumber: '',
              email: user.email
            },
            provider: false 
        })
    }
})
```

In the log, this function is called when a user is created but the user collection is not created.
Any idea? I'm new to functions so not sure why its not working.

Comment: `.onAuthStateChanged`

Comment: could you edt the function to demonstrate this? thx

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to create a cloud function with firebase functions to detect if the user emailVerified prop changes.

This isn't possible in Cloud Functions, as there's no trigger when the user object changes. The `onCreate` trigger you use (as its name implies) only triggers when the user is first created.

Having a trigger when the user profile changes would be a useful addition to Cloud Functions, so I recommend you [file feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report) for it.

The only workaround I can think of for now is to detect the `emailVerified` status client-side, call a [callable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) or [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) with the ID token, [verify that ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), and then store the `emailVerified` value to Firestore from there.

Comment: the reason im trying to do this is to avoid creating collections if a person is creating fake accounts etc. want to avoid creating user documents. is there a specifc way I can do this? Cuz if the user closes the website, and then verifies their email. Then I am unable to create their collection.

Comment: Or is there a way of sending the user to a custom page on my website when they verify their email so I can handle the logic there?

Comment: You'll need a trusted environment to verify their email address. I suggested Cloud Functions in my last paragraph, but that can also run another trusted environment. You can also let the clients create those collections themselves, and then [check whether their email is verified in the security rules of your database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50239804/209103).

Answer (score 0):

The [API reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged) shows:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  }
});
```